# Custom MVC route: changing where the views for a controller are located

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have a controller called EmployeeController, and all the Views are in /Employee.

I'd like to create a route so that the EmployeeController will use /Employees and /Employees/Add instead of /Employee and /Employee/Add.

I keep finding articles about how to change the route to go to different actions, but I couldn't find any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing Views with Routes.  ASP.NET MVC relies a lot on convention, and in this example it takes the controller component of the route an applies it to find the controller.  You can define a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Employees", "employees/{action}", new { 
    controller = "Employee",
    action = "Index" });
```

Comment: matthew - would you use a similar route convention if you were looking at the SO structure going from ../questions->../questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc etc... i.e. the 'tagged' controller isn't located at the 'top' level, but instead, parented by the questions controller. just a little quandry that i've had for a while

Comment: I think the important thing to remember is that you're not actually constrained to a `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route structure at all, that's just the standard *convention* for MVC routes.  In your example, you could define `questions/tagged/{tag}` before `questions/{id}/{name}/{comment}` and still have perfectly valid routes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are 2 different questions:

- First one is about **routes mapping** and here I'd agree on simple solution suggested by Matthew Abbott and Bugai13.
- Second one is about "Views" folder **conventions** and View files **resolution**. If you want some custom logic about that you may inherit `ViewResult` and change the way it finds the appropriate View file. You can also dive deeper into framework and tweak the way View is found and instantiated by creating your own `IViewEngine` or customizing one of those already existing.

It seems though, that all you need is first thing - just provide more specific route mappings with URL pattern like `employees/{action}` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rename EmployeeController to EmployeesController?  Then you don't have to mess with the route.

Of course you will then have to change your Views\Employee folder to Views\Employees as well.